# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: ELEMENT_NAME_MISMATCH

Tags: soap, spring-boot, cxf

I am new to **apache cxf**. I was using a cxf Interceptor to intercept my soap response and send a custom fault mesaage. Everything works fine when i try from Soap UI. But when i run tests , i get the correct response followed by this error "**org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: ELEMENT_NAME_MISMATCH**" due to which tests failed.

**Error** (The Weird thing is i get the soap response back before this error gets thrown)

```
   2016-11-28 21:49:16.371  WARN 8756 --- [main]          o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Interceptor for  {subscriptionservice/}SubscriptionServiceService#{subscriptionservice/}createSubscriptionEntity has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: ELEMENT_NAME_MISMATCH
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshallException(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:605)
    at   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:663)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter.processFaultDetail(ClientFaultConverter.java:155)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter.handleMessage(ClientFaultConverter.java:82)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1670)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1551)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1348)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:651)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy215.createSubscriptionEntity(Unknown Source)
    at tests.SubscriptionTests.dCreateSubscriptionWithNullValuesTSU08(SubscriptionTests.java:319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: ELEMENT_NAME_MISMATCH
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshallException(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:512)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you submit some of you configuration code?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have posted the config code

Comment: Note: It error out only in my tests.May be something to do with my test class

Comment: I think it is more related to unmarshalling. may be JAXBContext doesn't registered with the correct class instance which you are expecting in response.

Comment: You are right. Found out the error. Thank a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the error. Its because my test client wasn't able unmarshall the response properly due to mismatch in the QName. I was following a code first approach, so had to manually create a "package-info.java"  like this and mention my Qname.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "www.example.com/common/exceptions", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example.common.exceptions;
```